# Filter elements through a condition angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have defined the following array in my controller :

```
var people = [
        {
            name:"Alice",
            number:'808574629632',
            email:"navlanisahib1@gmail.com",
            rating:'100',
            id:0,
        },
        {
            name:"Bob",
            number:'808579632',
            email:"nsahib1@gmail.com",
            rating:'100',
            id:1,
        },
        {
            name:"Eve",
            number:'8085729632',
            email:"navlani1@gmail.com",
            rating:'47',
            id:2,
        },
    ];
```

I want to filter all the elements which are having the rating attribute greater than 50 . I have googled a lot about filtering elements through a condition using `'| filter:'` filters but did'nt find anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a function to be the filter expression on your controller. According to [docs for filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) a filter can be applyed like `{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator : anyPropertyKey}}` and also, the `expression` can be a string, an object or a function, which in this case fits perfectly for what you need assuming that you need to use `| filter`.

```
ng-repeat="person in people | filter:ratingGreaterThan50"

$scope.ratingGreaterThan50 = function (item) {
    return item.rating > 50;
}
```

The following snippet implements this custom filter solution:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {

    $scope.ratingGreaterThan50 = function(item) {
      return item.rating > 50;
    }

    $scope.people = [{
      name: "Alice",
      number: '808574629632',
      email: "navlanisahib1@gmail.com",
      rating: '100',
      id: 0,
    }, {
      name: "Bob",
      number: '808579632',
      email: "nsahib1@gmail.com",
      rating: '100',
      id: 1,
    }, {
      name: "Eve",
      number: '8085729632',
      email: "navlani1@gmail.com",
      rating: '47',
      id: 2,
    }, ];
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:ratingGreaterThan50">{{person.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```